# Defining App store links schemes in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, appstore-approval

I know that the App store links uses **itms://** **itms-apps://** and **itms-appss://** scheme. But according to this [WWDC Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/703/) we must define the external schemes in **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** after iOS 9.0. So are these three schemes needed to be defined in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes while calling canOpenUrl on any of those or Is just for the apps installed on the device.

In my app I haven't defined the schemes inside LSApplicationQueriesSchemes but canOpenUrl still returns True and I can open the application link in app store.

Comment: There is no need to add these schemes and call `canOpenUrl` with it unneeded too.